# how to extract first part of name(first name) in a list that contains full names and discard names with one part

Tags: python, list, csv, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a CSV file that contains one column of names. what I want is a python code to check every name in the column and see if the name has more than one part, it takes just the first part and appends it in a new CSV file list while it skips any name that has just one part in the old CSV file.

For Example

input CSV file

```
Column1
Metarhizium robertsii ARSEF 23
Danio rerio
Parascaris equorum
Hevea
Gossypium
Vitis vinifera
```

The output CSV file should be

```
Column1
Metarhizium
Danio
Parascaris
Vitis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split then apply the function `len` to mask the result, then get the first element of the filtered in rows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
splitted = df.Column1.apply(lambda x: x.split())
output = splitted[splitted.apply(len) > 1].apply(lambda x: x[0])
output.to_csv("output.csv")
# > ,Column1
#  0,Metarhizium
#  1,Danio
#  2,Parascaris
#  5,Vitis
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first create a flag for those values that have more than one word, then use the `apply()` method and write a lambda function to retrieve the first word in all names.

```
flag = df.loc[:,'Column1'].str.split(' ').apply(len) > 1
split_names = lambda name: name.split()[0] if (len(name.split())) else None
new_df = df.loc[flag,'Column1'].apply(split_names)
new_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the names always separated with a space?

You could use the `re` module in python and use regex expressions or if you looking for something simple you can also use the `str.split()` method in python:

```
for name in column:
    split_name = name.split(' ', 1) #Splits the name once after the first space and returns a list of strings
    if len(split_name) > 1: new_csv.write(split_name[0]) #write the first part of the split up name into the new csv
```